# Schengen Visa issued by Italian embassy but destination is Croatia

Tags: schengen

I have got my schengen visa from Italian embassy but they gave me C category SINGLE entry visa and I only want to visit croatia. is it possible I can go to croatia although my visa was issued by Italian embassy?

Comment: Why on earth did you apply for a visa from the Italian embassy if you had no intention of going to Italy? And why did they even consider the application? Did you make up a false Italy trip for applying?

Comment: @HenningMakholm How does your question actually help?

Answer (score 10):

Croatia will admit travelers who hold a Schengen visa only if that visa is valid for two or more entries.

With a single-entry Schengen visa, you will not be allowed to enter Croatia.  You should apply for a Croatian visa.

See http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/.